# Android kernel with MeeGo userspace?

Tags: android, meego

Not specifically a programming question, but I have not found another stackexchange to put it on.

What stops people from running the android kernel on their android devices, but instead of the Dalvik JVM and other android libraries, put MeeGo libraries instead? Wouldnt that be nice?